# google plus app logout button creation and functionality

Tags: ios, xcode5, google-plus

i have integrate google plus app in my iOS app and for this integration i followed google plus app official documentation i.e **https://developers.google.com/+/mobile/ios/sign-in#before_you_begin**. the login button works very well but after successful login, i am unable to logout because there is no logout button, so what i want is:-
1. after login it return to my app specific view controller(using segue) with logout button.
2. and on pressing logout button, it jump to my login view controller(or page).
 this functionality is exactly same as in Facebook app and also the sign out and disconnect method don't fulfill my  above mentioned requirements. 
so please help me on this. any help would be appreciated.

for your knowledge i am using plain view controllers(not a navigation controller).

Answer (score 0):

For Log out the user
`[[GPPSignIn sharedInstance] signOut]` method .

You can use the signOut method of the GPPSignIn object to sign out your user, for example:

```
- (void)signOut {
  [[GPPSignIn sharedInstance] signOut];
}
```

After logout you can present/pop your login view .

Comment: thank u for the help, but as i mentioned in my post ,both these methods does not fulfill my requirements(no. 1 and  no.2 ,see my post). i already try this. so please if you have other alternative then please suggest me and read my post carefully again, its a request.

Comment: plese help me on google plus logout button and it should be visible one. so that user can click on it.